# How to send input file name to args:Array[String] from a script in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a program reading one file and I want to read multiple files so I wrote a script to read those files and send them to the program (args in main) but some how it is not getting the input. I wanted to know the possible ways that I can send info to args(1).

Comment: How are you passing the arguments to the program? Could you provide the portion of your script that passes arguments to your Scala program?

Comment: I am trying to read many images and send them one by one to my program  using this script

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of piping the files to Java (via |) you should simply invoke your Scala program with the JPG argument appended. (I'm assuming Scala since that's what you have tagged your question with.)

Something like:

`scala YourScalaProgram tmp.jpg`

assuming that all necessary jars, etc., are on your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Since I am running my program using sbt is there anything I should do in my build.sbt  file?

Comment: It might be a little slower, since SBT has to load and run the build definition, and you'll get SBT output, but the following would work: `sbt "run tmp.arg"`. (The SBT run command and the file argument would need to be enclosed in double quotes.) Also, I'm assuming that your script runs from the SBT root directory and that there is only one program. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah everything is on the right place and I moved out other programs from my directory. At least now I am getting other errors related to OpenCV library. Thanks for your time